# Resolução de Conflitos no Git

Tags: git, github, merge

Boas tardes,
Trabalho com o gestor de versões Git, e por sua vez ao fazer merge deparo-me com conflitos complicados de resolver. Existe alguma ferramenta que permita de alguma forma lidar melhor com estes conflitos? O ideal seria uma ferramenta que permitisse organizar o código e coloca-lo em "linhas especificas".
Por exemplo ao fazer merge com um código que está em master e houver funções que tenham espaços alguns desses espaços são preenchidos por código meu, e não era suposto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo que preciso realizar com o Git, eu utilizo no [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/). Ele é uma ferramenta com interface para diversas (senão todas) do Git, diversas facilidades e velocidade para realizar atividades do Git, em comparação ao `bash`, como:

1. `auto-stash` dos seus arquivos, se tiver alterações ao trocar de branch;
2. Facilidade para seguir o padrão [GitFlow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow);
3. Mensagens de merges padronizadas durante todo o projeto;
4. Facilidade em cliques nos botões como `undo`, `redo`, `pull`, `branch`, `stash`, `pop`;
5. Melhor visibilidade de todo o fluxo que houve, bem como histórico de `commits`, em comparação ao `gitk`;
6. Facilidade para realizar `commits`, e verificar cada linha que foi adicionada/removida;
7. Facilidade para ignorar arquivos e/ou selecionar apenas alguns arquivos para `commitar`;
8. Facilidade para descartar todas as alterações realizadas em diversos arquivos.

*Estas são as principais que eu utilizo, mas há mais funcionalidades...*

Em relação ao merge, ele possui um `merge tool` que divide a tela em dois, onde à esquerda fica o seu arquivo alterado, e na direita fica o arquivo que está vindo da develop, no caso de um merge da sua branch na develop. Pode-se então selecionar um bloco, ou clicar linha à linha, e na parte de baixo mostra-se o arquivo final.

Realizado todos os conflitos, apenas clique em `Commit and merge files` que o merge é realizado, em seguida pode ser realizado o `push` com um simples clique no botão.

Segue abaixo uma imagem que demonstra isto melhor:

[image: mergetool]

Também há outra ferramenta parecida, o [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). Ele é semelhante ao GitKraken, porém a desvantagem é que não há para Linux, apenas Mac ou Windows, então eu particularmente acabei não usando este.

Hoje em dia também os próprios editores, como [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), há uma própria ferramenta para resolver conflitos de `merge`, onde você pode clicar nos `links`, ou fazer a alteração de forma manual, com uma melhor visibilidade nas linhas que estão vindo da branch que você está fazendo o `merge`, e a branch que você está.

Segue uma imagem abaixo que mostra isto melhor:

[image: vscode]